# How to do "pollling" or "select" on async generators with asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

Suppose I have several async generators:

```
import asyncio

async def genA():
  for i in range(10):
    yield f'A : {i}'
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

async def genB():
  for i in range(10):
    yield f'B : {i}'
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

async def genC():
  for i in range(10):
    yield f'C : {i}'
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Is there a way to easily iterate awaiting for any generator (polling or socket select equivalent for async generators) ?
...For example getting each time a tuple (generator, value) ?

...With only python standard library ?

Comment: sorry, can you explain a little more? i didn't get it

Comment: See my answer, I actually wanted to "merge" the generators

Answer (score 0):

Reading further the documentation, I found the Queue object. This "aggregate" function could be implemented like this :

```
async def consumer(agen, q):
  async for x in agen:
    q.put_nowait((agen, x))
  q.put_nowait(None)

async def aggregate(*agen):
  q = asyncio.Queue()
  counter = len(agen)
  for ag in agen :
    asyncio.create_task(consumer(ag, q))
  while counter :
    if (v := await q.get()) is None:
      counter -= 1
    else:
      yield v
```